# Can't get Waypoints with jQuery to work (trouble running scripts in html)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-waypoints

I cannot figure out how to get Waypoints to run on my site.

It feels like it is a problem with how (or to what) I am linking the scripts in my html body. So it may not be a Waypoints problem at all, rather a really n00b html problem... Right now, I have it like this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js" defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/2.0.4/waypoints.min.js" defer></script>
<script src="js/script.js" defer></script>
```

Basically, the my javascript that uses Waypoints won't fire, and I get an error like this when I load the page:

[Error looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhgMV.png)

Any help would be so appreciated!

Thanks :)
Aaron

Comment: It looks like the `waypoints` script it is loaded before `jquery` so loose the `defer` attribute

Comment: Put `http:` before the url in the jquery script so that it is `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js`

Comment: You two are saints, thank you! I tried both at once so I'm not certain which fixed it! But thank you so much!

Comment: Site not giving me the option to "mark as solved" but this question is solved!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed both pieces of the advice below, and lo-and-behold, it worked! I think it was the defer issue...

[Solution!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEbyY.png)